# Calling cellForRowAtIndexPath from within heightForRowAtIndexPath — alternate?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` from within `heightForRowAtIndexPath` in order to assign a height based on the cell's type (I'm subclassing `UITableViewCell`). Trivial, right? Well, calling it there causes a loop. I can't quite seem to figure out why that would be. Placing breakpoints in both methods doesn't yield anything—the delegate method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` never actually gets called. Take a look:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
       return SubclassCellTypeOne()
    default:
       return SubclassCellTypeTwo()
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    // Calling cellForRowAtIndexPath here causes a loop
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    if cell is SubclassCellTypeOne {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    } else {
        return 100
    }
}
```

Any idea why that's happening? And any suggestions on how to get around it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a reference to a cell is made via a `UITableView`, (usually by iOS, when loading your view), iOS calls the methods in its lifecycle - e.g., `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` to work out how to display it etc.

So your source of an infinite loop is that you make a reference to a cell, inside a method that is called when a reference to a cell is made ;)

To fix this, you should reference back to your data source, instead of asking the cell directly about itself. If you have a class set up as a data collection, this is easy.

Comment: Hmmm. That makes sense. I've updated the code based on your answer. This looks hairy but it's working... oddly enough... 

let cell = tableView.dataSource?.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

Comment: Better, but you're still referencing your data through your `UITableView`. You should have a class or at least an array or something somewhere with your original data in, that you called in your data delegate. Refer back to *that*, using `indexPath.row` as a pointer to the element that you want.

Comment: I would do that except that I'll be adding and removing cells pretty regularly so storing the cells in an immutable structure wouldn't really make sense. Unless that structure can be changed with the tableView. Do you think that would do the trick?

Comment: So make it a mutable data structure! The whole idea of binding you data to the delegate is that when your data changes, so does the tableView. Don't think of updating the tableView, or doing actions on the tableView, just do everything on the data structure and the tableView will be updated accordingly (so long as you remember to do `tableView.reloadData()`

Your tableView is just that - a view. Try to decouple your data and application logic as much as possible from your tableView.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you shouldn't call cellForRow inside heightForRow.
In heightForRow you have the indexPath variable. You can use indexPath.row to determine the class of the cell inside heightForRow, just like you do in cellForRow.

You could also have forgotten to set the delegate and datasource properties of the tableview. Or you are returning 0 from numberOfRowsInTable...
That could also be why you are not hitting the breakpoint inside cellForRow.

Comment: I've simplified the code by _quite_ a bit. The table view is pretty dynamic and will have cells added and removed pretty regularly with different heights based on the type. So instead of using tons of switches and if-else's to determine the height I'm relying on the type.

Comment: Hahaha, I don't ever forget to set those ;)